# How do I pin a website to the shelf on ChromeOS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

On ChromeOS I can pin apps to the shelf. How can I pin an arbitrary website to the shelf?

Answer (score 1):

As of Chrome 63 (December 2017):

1. Navigate to the page you want to pin.
2. Open the Chrome menu (three dots in the top-right corner of the window).
3. Click **Create shortcut...**

This feature moved to the top-level menu in [63.03214.0](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/63.0.3213.3..63.0.3214.0?pretty=fuller&n=10000) ([commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/72a04d3d2176bd351d1c9ba0d3f8c1c13c258a53), [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=629725)).

In older versions of Chrome:

1. Navigate tot he page you want to pin.
2. Open the Chrome menu.
3. Open the **More tools** menu.
4. Click **Add to shelf...**

Sources: [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-add-a-website-to-your-chromebook-shelf-4103594), [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/232508/how-to-make-a-taskbar-icon-for-any-website-on-a-chromebook/)